# In medieval England was heresy dealt with in the king's courts or church courts?

Tags: middle-ages, england, crime

In medieval England was heresy dealt with in the kings courts or church courts?

Clearly heresy was a crime against the church but the punishment was death so presumably it must have been dealt with in the royal courts as, to the best of my knowledge, church courts did not sentence people to death. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that Heresy was an offence dealt with by the Church courts.  However, the church courts could indeed sentence heretics to death.

If convicted, the offender was then handed over to the State for that sentence to be carried out.

---

However, this does not mean that the State ordered the death of the offender. They merely carried out the sentence.  They also had no discretion in the matter.  As noted in the paper [A Brief History of Medieval Roman Canon Law in England](https://scholarship.law.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=7774&context=penn_law_review), the situation was made clear by the English Canonist, [William Lyndwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lyndwood) in 1430:

> In other words, "heresy was in his view a spiritual crime, and it was for the Church, not for the State, to say what should be done with heretics. If a lay prince refused to execute the Church's law concerning this crime, he was to be excommunicated."

- Charles P. Sherman, [A Brief History of Medieval Roman Canon Law in England](https://scholarship.law.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=7774&context=penn_law_review), University of Philadelphia Law Review, Vol. 68, No. 3 (March 1920), pp233-258

---

There is a detailed exploration of how heresy was dealt with by the church courts in medieval England in Ian Forrest's 2005 book, [The Detection of Heresy in Late Medieval England](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wMhSDKhLelgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

---

So, to summarise, heretics were charged by the church courts, convicted by the church courts, and sentenced by the church courts.

Only then were those heretics handed over to the State for that sentence to be carried out.

Comment: It's worth remembering that Church and State were *much* less distinct back then.

Comment: @MarkOlson Not in matters of legal jurisdiction.

Comment: @MarkOlson - Viewing [**"heresy as treason"**](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199212484.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199212484-e-015) wasn't something new. Persecution of the Lollards had statutory basis, [**"De heretico comburendo"**](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095707587). I thought this was a nice, neat answer.

Comment: @J Aia: Precisely my point: Heresy can only be treason if Church and State are intertwined i a way that is rare today.

Comment: @MarkOlson Actually, heresy as treason only really became a thing in the Early Modern period, where [disagreement with the monarch's religion became inseparable from treason](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/education/candp/crime/g04/g04cs2.htm). The Lollards were actually often tolerated by the English State (though not by the church) until a prominent Lollard, John Ball, took a leading roll in the Peasants' Revolt.  Until there was an overlap of interest both Church and State were very clear about their separate legal jurisdictions.

Comment: Hmmm, this is interesting - I agreed with Mark on lack of distinction so I provided more info, yet I did not see Sempaiscuba's comment on *distinct legal jurisdiction* as inconsistent. This is getting to a deeper level of legal discussion (which wasn't my intention).  Ecclesiastical courts had jurisdiction because of their expertise, but the basis for prosecuting was not  in canon law (laws made by Church/Christian leaders) but statutory (laws made by Sovereign, later Parliament). This was the distinction I thought Sempaiscuba meant. If I don't make any sense, just ignore my earlier comment.

Comment: The situation is not fundamentally different from that in the Roman empire. For example, Jesus (according to the gospels) was tried and found guilty by the Jewish religious court, and then handed over to the Roman governor for execution.